# Table view scrolls with Navigation bar title

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a simple `UITableView` in my view controller with a navigation bar (large title). However, when testing my app, the navigation bar title scrolls along with the table view, which is incorrect behaviour.

[Video of the issue](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/I0q6JNVZGB8)

[Image of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoR4J.png)

Comment: Not sure it is unwanted behaviour : when using large title the title is tight to the content, when inline it is stick at top.